# import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication

Uncaught SyntaxError in auth.service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I already put type = 'module' in package.jason file.

I need to @Injectable({
providedIn: 'root',
})
to decorate class AuthService but above error shows. Can somebody help me?thank you!

Comment: hello, it should not happen with default angular configuration.
Please show the code of your service.